# How to change color of selected items in LongListMultiSelector?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I've got a LongList **Multi** Selector and want to change the color of the border in selected state from phoneAccentBrush to a static value.

[image]

Unfortunately I was not able to find an itemStyle that fits.

Where do I get a copy of the standard style or how do I change the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

It's open source. You can open and edit a copy in Blend.

**EDITED**

Sorry didn't notice your Grid layout. The previous style was for the List layout of MLLS.
In order to achieve what you want you need to change the `SelectionRectangle` Rectangle Stroke and `SelectionTriangle` Polyline Fill to the desired brush.

```
<Style x:Key="LongListMultiSelectorItemGridStyle" TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionTriangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionCheck">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HasSelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionRectangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterCover">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="1" >
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                Margin="3"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionRectangle" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                        <Polyline x:Name="SelectionTriangle" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Points="50,0 50,50 0,0"
                                Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                            />
                        <Polyline x:Name="SelectionCheck" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Points="40,0 43,3 28,18 18,8 21,5 28,12"
                                Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                                />
                        <Grid x:Name="OuterCover" IsHitTestVisible="True" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm a bit slow on the uptake today...
Can you point out, where exactly I have to change something to achieve a change of the border / checkmark-background color?

Comment: Thank you so much! Works as expected :)